# How to use same columns multiple times in where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

How to use same columns multiple times in where condition. I want to use 'meta_key' and 'meta_value' multiple times. But unfortunately, It is not working.

I have used left join statements, But it didn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` d 
JOIN (select distinct product_id from products 
    WHERE (meta_key="product_image" AND meta_value!="") 
AND
(meta_key="product_type" AND meta_value="Soap" ) 
And
user_id='6' LIMIT 10) t on d.product_id = t.product_id
```

Empty Result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get products that have both keys,

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p join
     (SELECT product_id 
      FROM cs_inventory 
      WHERE ((meta_key = 'product_image' AND meta_value <> '') OR
             (meta_key = 'product_type' AND meta_value= 'Soap' )
            ) AND
            user_id = 6
      GROUP BY product_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
      LIMIT 10
     ) i
     ON p.product_id = i.product_id;
```

One row cannot have multiple values for a single column, so your subquery will never return any value.

Instead, this uses `OR` and checks that both rows are available for the product.

Comment: is it possible to use sub query in where condition, I mean add "OR  (select count(product_id) from product_images WHERE product_id= '123'"

Comment: @TahaFarooqui . . . Yes it is, assuming you have a comparison afterwards for the `count()` (or no comparison is needed if you are just checking that the value is not zero).  Often it is better to use `exists`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish but from what I can see so far, you use the requirements

```
WHERE (meta_key = "product_image" AND meta_value != "") AND
      (meta_key = "product_type" AND meta_value = "SOAP") AND
```

These right here are conflicting arguments. `meta_key` cannot be both `product_image` and `product_type`. I think what you are looking for is `OR`.

```
WHERE (meta_key = "product_image" AND meta_value != "") OR
      (meta_key = "product_type" AND meta_value = "SOAP")
```

Additionally, I'm unsure if this is correct being fairly new to SQL myself, but `WHERE` usually follows the `JOIN`  `ON` clause. For example,

```
 JOIN (select distinct product_id from cs_inventory) ON
      d.product_id = t.product_id
 WHERE ((meta_key = "product_image" AND meta_value != "") OR
       (meta_key = "product_type" AND meta_value = "SOAP")) AND 
       (user_id = '6')
 LIMIT 2;
```